# Задача. Node.JS Clusters с множеством серверов и ядер

Tags: node.js, cluster

Всем привет, попалась мне одна задачка, но никак не могу её решить! Может вы мне поможете? Значит суть в чём:

|| У нас есть допустим 40 серверов, у которых есть к примеру по 30-40 ядер. Каждое ядро обрабатывает поступающие в них запросы. Запросов может быть примерно тысяча в секунду.

? Вопрос, каким образом после обработки 1 000 000 запросов всеми ядрами. Временно остановить работу на всех ядрах.

! Важная информация:

1) Мы не знаем точное количество серверов.

2) Мы не знаем точное количество ядер на каждом сервере

3) Мы должны остановить работу на всех ядрах, именно после 1 000 000 запроса. То, есть мы должны недопустить обработку 1 000 001 запроса

4) используется нативный модуль cluster

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял, то имеется 40 отдельных серверов с 30-40 ядрами, на каждом запущен кластер. И на все это льется трафик через балансировщик.

Тогда идея такая: поступает запрос, который проходит "аутентификацию", если лимит превышен, запрещаем дальнейшую передачу на NodeJS сервера.

На примере модуля [http_auth_request_module](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/) из Nginx:

```
http {

    # балансировщик - тут наши 40 серверов
    upstream backend  {
      server nodejs1.site.com;
      server nodejs2.site.com;
      server nodejs3.site.com;
      # ...
    }

    server {

        # сюда идут запросы
        location /nodejs/ {
          # если аутентификации нет, дальше запросы не пойдут
          auth_request /auth;
          # проксируем на бек NodeJS
          proxy_pass  http://backend;
        }

        # тут проводим проверку
        location = /auth {
          internal;
          proxy_pass http://auth.site.com;
          proxy_pass_request_body off;
          proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
          #...
        }

    }

}
```

Осталось только на http://auth.site.com начать точно считать до 1 млн:

```
'use strict';

const
  express = require('express'),
  app = express()
  ;

let
  numRequests = 0,
  // лимит:
  requestsLimit = 1000000
  ;

app.all(/.*/, function(req, res) {
    if(numRequests >= requestsLimit) {
      res.status(403).send('Limit is over!');
      return;
    }
    numRequests++;
    res.send(`ok: ${numRequests}`);
});

app.listen(80);
```

Этот скрипт также можно повесить на тот же сервер с Nginx, только поменять порт (или не менять, если добавить еще конфигов Nginx).